# Можно ли интегрировать код написанный на C++ в Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, c++

Есть библиотека написанная на `c++`. Для работы библиотеки нужно дергать методы. Можно ли вставить проект написанный на `c++` в `Android/Java` и через `java` обращаться и получать данные из `c++`?

Comment: можно. Но тема крайне большая. Советую почитать про NDK и jni(там куча всего с примерами) https://habr.com/post/203014/ вот чтобы понять о чём речь

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code